# How can I perform build time enhancement of JPA entities while running an Arquillian test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, openjpa, jboss-arquillian, openjpa-maven-plugin

Technology stack: Arquillian embedded-tomee, HSQLDB, openJpa, jdk 1.8.

I have spent several days trying to figure out how I can get this all to work together and have come very close IMO. And now I am stuck with this one very generic error.

```
<openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 fatal general error>
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
```

I have all my entities added to the `test-persistence.xml` and is correctly placed under `src/test/resources`.

**The Initial Problem**
I tried setting `Runtime Unenhanced Classes` to `supported` and hoped that the enhancement would occur at runtime inside the `Arquillian-Embedded-Tomee` container. Had no luck there. Kept getting the error that some of my entities didn't have a public/protected no-args constructor which is required for runtime enhancement.
**NOTE**: The runtime enhancement works perfectly fine inside the **actual** deployed tomee container. Just doesn't work inside Arquillian.

**First Approach to solve the above problem:**
I didn't want to expose my entities as public. So switched to `build-time-enhancement` using the `openjpa maven plugin` as described [here](http://people.apache.org/~dwoods/openjpa/site/enhancement-with-maven.html).
Had some success with this approach. Could actually see and verify that while running `mvn clean install` the enities were being enhanced.

**build output:**

```
 --- openjpa-maven-plugin:1.2:enhance---
some-persistent-unit  INFO   [main] openjpa.Tool - Enhancer running on 
type "class someClass".
some-persistent-unit  INFO   [main] openjpa.Tool - Enhancer running on 
type "class someotherclass".
```

and so on...

But the problem here is:
The tests pass only during maven build. If I try to run the individual tests in a test class or all of the tests in that test class, they fail. And also in this approach I disabled the runtime support for unenhanced classes in my persistence-context.

```
<property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported"/>
```

because of which I concluded that the `openjpa-maven-plugin` was working as expected.

Question 1: Is this the expected behavior? Do the tests not work outside of a maven build?
Question 2: Is the openjpa plugin providing a `javaagent` behind the scenes?

**Not knowing what to do, I switched to a different(???) approach:**
Tried running enhancement using `javaagent` as described to a similar question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651500/arquillian-integration-tests-and-openjpa-enhancement). Had no success with this.
Ended up with the below error:

```
<<< ERROR! org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: This 
configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types 
were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent: "
List of entities described in test-persistence.xml
```

Question 3: **So how can I set up build time enhancement, and also make sure that the enhancements work for every unit test that I run?**

Question 4: **Even better how can I(If popssible) set up build time enhancement to occur only for tests running inside of Arquillian.**

Or am I approaching this all wrong to begin with?

Comment: As for Question 4, tried [this](http://people.apache.org/~mikedd/openjpa/openjpa-maven-plugin/examples/testenhance.html). Ended up with same error:
`ERROR!
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent: "`

Comment: Could share your project on GitHub for example? I think it's too specific question to answer without running it first.

Comment: @bartosz.majsak I cannot share the project where I am facing this problem. But I will spin up a quick mock up of the scenario and post it.

Comment: Awesome, just share a github url and I will see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: if your IDE doesnt run openjpa plugin but only do a compilation then you'll miss the enhancement yes

Q2: no, both the plugin and javaagent uses the same enhancement implementation but you can see them as different hooks (build vs runtime)

Q3: depends your IDE, with eclipse you need the lifecycle plugin to configure openjpa and with Intellij you need to add openjpa:enhance after Make phase in the run configuration

Q4: with tomee remote it is done automatically

I think using the javaagent is still the best way to solve the enhancement, you really just need to ensure maven and/or your test configuration have -javaagent:/path/to/openejb-javaagent.jar